# How to expand "word" in bash? Not talking about file wildcards

Tags: bash, cat, echo

Sorry for so simple question, but I could not find a solution myself.

I run:

```
$ echo {1..4}
1 2 3 4
```

And that's OK to me. But if I:

```
$ echo "{1..4}" > file

$ cat file
{1..4}

$ echo $(<file)
{1..4}

$ echo $(cat file)
{1..4}
```

I'm looking for a way to expand the string `{1..4}` that's inside the file `file` using `echo`, without success.

Comment: Do you want the file to contain `1 2 3 4` or do you want the file to contain `{1..4}` and expand it to `1 2 3 4` when you read the contents?

Comment: Are you looking to use the shell's brace expansion in particular, or do you just want to read two numbers off a file and generate a list based on them? Because you could of course just read the file and evaluate the contents as part of a shell command, but if the file had other expansions, the shell would process those too. Including e.g. command substitutions, meaning that the shell could be made to run any command, including stuff like `rm -rf ~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
eval "echo $(cat file)"
```

eval constructs a command which is then executed by the shell.

Comment: This, of course is subject to all the caveats of `eval` in general. If the file contains e.g. `; date` or `$(date >&2)`, you'll get the current date on your screen. And of course it could be `rm -rf` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are just not using the right tool for the job:

```bsh
[user@host dir]$ ksh
$ echo "{1..4}" > file
$ cat file
{1..4}
$ echo $(<file)
1 2 3 4
$ echo $(cat file)
1 2 3 4
```

Jokes aside, the [order of expansions in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) is:

1. brace expansion;
2. tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion);
3. word splitting;
4. and filename expansion.

Thus, in `echo $(cat file)`, the output of the (unquoted) command substitution undergoes word splitting and filename expansion only—remaining unchanged because it doesn't include pattern matching characters (and assuming your `IFS` variable does not include `{`, `1`, `.`, `4` or `}`).

While some expansions can be nested, the *result* of an expansion is generally not parsed again for characters that would trigger expansions from stages up to the current one. (For good reasons: think about `foo=\$foo; echo "$foo"`).

To have brace expansion applied to the content of `file` you need to build a new command line and let the shell parse and execute it. One way is `eval`, as shown in [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598902/315749) you have. Alternatively, you may use process substitution:

```bsh
$ . <(printf '%s ' echo; cat file)
1 2 3 4
```

Note that, in both cases, *the whole content of `file` will be parsed and executed* in the current environment.

Similarly, but executing in the separate environment of a new `bash` process:

```bsh
$ bash <<<$( printf "%s " echo; cat file; )
1 2 3 4
```

As an aside, ksh93 (the shell I used in my first code block) behaves in a peculiar way: brace expansion is performed at a later stage, as part of field splitting, and the result of previous expansions is parsed anew to detect brace expressions<sup>1</sup>:

```bsh
$ bash -c 'echo {1..$(printf %s 3)}' mybash
{1..3}
$ ksh -c 'echo {1..$(printf %s 3)}' myksh
1 2 3
```

---

<sup>1</sup> 
<sub>As Stéphane Chazelas [noted in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598898/how-to-expand-word-in-bash-not-talking-about-file-wildcards/598926#comment1118251_598926), this behavior of ksh93 can be considered a bug and is not POSIX conformant, since it makes it possible for `$var` not to expand to the value of `var`.</sub>

Comment: Jokes aside, Bash's choice of doing brace expansion first is really unfortunate, and makes many things harder. Zsh doesn't seem to expand braces from parameters either, but it probably has an option to do that, even though I can't find one now.

Comment: @ilkkachu, that behaviour of `ksh93` that brace expansion is done upon word expansions is a bug (and source of vulnerabilities) that will hopefully be fixed in future versions. It's also a non-POSIX conformance (as noted relatively recently by the austin group). In `zsh`, `echo {1..$var}` works, but `print -r -- $var` is guaranteed to output the contents of `$var` (unless you enable shwordsplit / globsubst but those  only for  sh compatibility)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yes, I mostly meant just `{$i..$j}` not working in Bash, should have been more clear. Didn't put too much thought in the implications of that ksh behaviour.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Please feel free to add a note about the ksh93's bug/security issue to my answer. I'd do it, since what I wrote may be read as a suggestion to use that feature, but I have no knowledge about the issue and I could only quote your comment.

Comment: It's mostly about `$var` not expanding to the contents of `$var` (and to several words instead of one) when you expect it to.

Comment: @ilkkachu zsh seems to have the sanest approach: brace expressions are parsed and evaluated along with parameter expansions, command substitutions etc, so that `i=1 j=3; {$i..$j}` expands to `1` `2` `3` and `x={1..3}; echo $x` expands to `{1..3}`. Without the oddities of Bash (`a=b; echo {,$}a`, `echo {a,b}$((++c))`) and those of ksh mentioned in this A.

Comment: @fra-san, "zsh seems to have the sanest approach" is not a very surprising sentence actually.